# How to display CSV data as a table view on html page using flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I'm using Python 3.7.7 and working on the following:

I have a directory with csv files that are being created in this folder daily:

```
daily-2020-08-19.csv
daily-2020-08-18.csv
daily-2020-08-17.csv
... and so on...
```

structure of my data file is sorted by customers:

```
daily-2020-08-17.csv
userId, calls, customers, emails
  2       0       11        30
  1       1       5         11
  3       11      0         0
    daily-2020-08-18.csv
userId, calls, customers, emails
  1       11      15       5
  2       0       2        5
  3       1       1        1
  5       0       1        1
  4       0       0        0
daily-2020-08-19.csv
userId, calls, customers, emails
  2       13      30       55
  1       11      15       5
  5       3       3        5
  3       2       2        1
  4       1       1        3
  7       1       1        1
  6       10      0        5
```

userId = numbers of active users on a given day. With time there is expected a higher number of Ids as new users are registering everyday.

I've managed to sum data for the last 3 days using pandas and now I have 3days.csv:

```
userId, customers
  2        43
  1        35
  5        4
  3        3
  4        1
  7        1
  6        0
```

How can I display the above data as a table view on html page using flask? I'm completely new to flask and aiming to have userId showing in my table as an URL which would then bring me to a separate html page specific to that particular userID.

My code so far:

```
from flask import Flask
import os

app = Flask (__name__)

#fun var

filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'path/to/my/3days.csv')

open_read = open(filepath,'r')
page =''

while True:
    read_data = open_read.readline()
    page += '<p>%s</p>' % read_data
    if open_read.readline() == '':
        break

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return page


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

With the above code I managed to get only some values from my 3days.csv. However I need a table view with userId as URL that brings to web page dedicated to the particular userId. Could someone help with this?

Output:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In table_page.html:

```
<table>
{% for a_user in page %}
  <tr>
    <td><a href="{% url_for 'user_page', a_user.userId %}">User# {{ a_user.userId }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ a_user.customers }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

In views.py:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    # page need to be a list, like [{'userId': '2', 'customers': '43'},{'userId': '1', 'customers': '35'}, ...]
    return render_template("table_page.html", page=page)
```

Then make a user page:

```
@app.route('user_page/<id>')
def user_page(id=None):
  ....
```

To convert `3days.csv` into the `page` list (assuming it is a string variable and not a csv file.  If it is a csv file, you'll need to file.read() it):

```
pages = []
lines =  3days_text.split('\n')

for line in lines:
  line_as_list = line.split(",")
  pages.append({'userId': line_as_list[0], 'customers': line_as_list[1])
```